# Derivatives using the chain rules

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

I am having problems correctly solving the given question, in which I must solve for $V$, $\frac{dl}{dt}$ for cm/h and m/h, $l$ and the rate of change:

A cubical block of ice is melting in such a way that each edge decreases steadily by 5.5 cm every hour. At what rate is its volume decreasing when each edge is 10 meters long?

My solution is:

$V = l^3\\
\frac{dl}{dt} = 5.5_{cm/h} = 0.055_{m/h} \\
\frac{dV}{dt} = 16.50_{m^3/h}$

where $\frac{dV}{dt} = 3(l)^2 \frac{dr}{dt} \\
 = 3(l)^2 (0.055) \\
= 16.50$

Please notify me on any missteps I have made as this is the incorrect solution to the given problem.

Comment: The $dr/dt$ should be $dl/dt$. And the negative sign noted below. Can you post what the correct answer is?

Answer (score 0):

The answer (and $\frac{dl}{dt}$) should be negative.  Remember, the sides and volume are *decreasing*, so the derivatives should be negative.